# NullPointerException after logging in when using OWASP CSRFGuard 3.0

Tags: java, csrf, owasp

I am attempting to use the latest OWASP CSRFGuard (v3.0).  After I log into my web application locally, I get the following error:

```
[8/12/13 7:14:58:792 EDT] 00000023 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown
 by one of the service methods of the servlet [action] in application [GuidingStars]. Exception created : [java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.getSessionValue(SessionData.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.session.SessionData.getAttribute(SessionData.java:163)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuard.updateToken(CsrfGuard.java:395)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener.java:13)
```

I have setup my csrfguard.properties file in a "barebones" fashion (see below) but still am getting this error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Here's my properties file:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger

org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN

org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN

org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenLength=32

org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG=SHA1PRNG
```

Comment: @param83 - can't remember...sorry.  That was at a previous job/project...